# Gradle: Exclude distinct resource files in assembly

Tags: gradle, source-sets

Gradle 2.5

I have several resource bundle files. Some of them I want to exclude from beeing packaged in the destination jar file, because they do not contain yet authorized translations.

According to documentation and examples I found I have this directive:

```
sourceSets {
   main {
        resources {
            exclude 'mail/mailtext_it.properties'
        }
    }
}
```

and asserting that this directive is correctly interpreted by printing out the fileset of the main resources:

```
processResources 
{
    afterEvaluate 
    {
        println "resource files (in processResources): " + sourceSets['main'].resources.getFiles()
    }
}
```

When running "gradle clean assembly", the print out of the resource set is indeed what I expect (excluded files are NOT listed there), but the build/resource/ folder still contains the files, and they are present in the destination jar too.

What I am missing? Which task is responsible for copying the resource files to the build directory, based on which source set?

Comment: Just a guess, I suppose that excluding files from source sets just make them not processed at processing resources phase. To exclude them from archive. If you need to exclude them from jar file you need to configure `exclude` block inside a `jar` block. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) are useful docs.

Comment: My understanding so far is: processResources copies (and filters) the files to the build directory (as the compile task compiles the source files into the build dir), and the jar task picks up the prepared artifacts (compiled, filtered) from build dir and packages them into a jar. Is this picture wrong?

Comment: It works as you wrote. No idea why the script fails to exclude the files correctly - [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33347557) `lol` and `lol3` files should be included in the final jar.

Comment: I really hate this kind of config (using excludes). Rather than dumping everything in `src/main/resources` and using `excludes`, why not put them  in `src/unauthorized/resources` and add them when required? Much cleaner IMHO and less *magic* to remember

Comment: @Opal: Thanks a lot for your effort. Your demo works as expected - of course ;-). My project setup, unfortunatly, is much more complicated (multi-module project, resource filtering which has itself excludes, etc.). We going productive tomorrow, so I have no time anymore to fiddle out on this problem. I'll just remove the concerned properties files from the the trunk and go.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the filter directive in the processResources was the culprit:

```
processResources 
{
    // Note: narrow the file set to be filtered. Otherwise gradle would change the jks file
    // when copying to output folder !!!
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include '**/*.properties'
        filter ( org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, 
             tokens: [
                        "filtervar.walletservice.productVersion": project.property("filtervar.walletservice.productVersion"),
                     ]  
            )    
    }
}
```

Obviuosly the from(...) clause overrides the definition of the sourceSets definition. I would have expected that it would be cumulative.

I solved it by definining the from(..) like:

```
from( sourceSets['main'].resources ) {
    include '**/*.properties'
    ...
```